# Kommt vor "dass" ein Komma, wenn es zusammen mit einem Verbindungswort steht?

Tags: punctuation, comma

Wenn ein Nebensatz durch ein "dass" eingeleitet wird, muss bekanntlich ein Komma notiert werden:

> Ich finde es gut, dass ich groß bin.

Was aber ist wenn vor dem "dass" noch ein Verbindungswort kommt?

> Es ist wichtig zu wissen, dass das Komma notiert werden muss und dass
>   es eine Regel dafür gibt.

Weiteres Beispiel:

> Ein Problem, auf das man immer wieder stoßen kann, ist dass man nicht
>   weiter weiß.

Muss bei "und dass" und "ist dass" jetzt noch irgendwo ein Komma stehen und wenn ja, wo?

Vor oder nach dem Verbindungswort? Kann mir jemand die Regeln dafür nennen?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Die amtliche deutsche Rechtschreibung (2006) besagt in § 72

> Sind die gleichrangigen Teilsätze, Wortgruppen oder Wörter durch *und, oder, 
>   beziehungsweise/bzw., sowie (= und), wie (= und), entweder
>   … oder, nicht … noch, sowohl … als (auch), sowohl … wie
>   (auch) oder durch weder … noch* verbunden, so setzt man kein
>   Komma.
>
> [...] Beispiel:
>
> *Ich hoffe, dass es dir gefällt und dass du zufrieden bist.*

Also ist der Satz in der Frage korrekt:

> Es ist wichtig zu wissen, dass das Komma notiert werden muss und dass es eine Regel dafür gibt.

Beim zweiten Beispiel trifft die obige Regel nicht zu, da die beiden Nebensätze (ein Relativsatz mit Präposition und ein [Prädikativsatz](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4dikativsatz)) nicht mit einer Konjunktion wie *und* verbunden sind und auch nicht zusammenhängen.

Korrekt ist also

> Ein Problem, auf das man immer wieder stoßen kann, ist, dass man nicht weiter weiß.

Comment: Du warst eine Minute schneller `:-)`

Answer (score 18):

Im Beispiel

> Es ist wichtig zu wissen, dass das Komma notiert werden muss und dass es eine Regel dafür gibt.

sind zwei gleichrangige Nebensätze durch das Verbindungswort *und* verbunden – und in diesem Fall [wird in der Tat kein Komma gesetzt](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibregeln/komma#K122). Anders ist das bei verbundenen Hauptsätzen, dort [kann ein Komma gesetzt werden](http://www.duden.de/sprachratgeber/crashkurs--in-25-schritten-zur-neuen-rechtschreibung/7#Regel%2020):

> Ich gehe ins Schwimmbad[,] oder ich besuche ein Konzert.

(Nach alter Rechtschreibung muss das Komma gesetzt werden.)

Im zweiten Beispiel

> Ein Problem, auf das man immer wieder stoßen kann, ist dass man nicht weiter weiß.

ist *ist* kein Verbindungswort, und nach *ist* muss ein weiteres Komma gesetzt werden. Der Hauptsatz ist *Ein Problem ist*, und danach kommt das Komma. Alternativ kann man den Satz zwecks Kommareduzierung auch umformulieren:

> Man kann immer wieder auf das Problem stoßen, dass man nicht weiter weiß.

Comment: +1 für gute Antwort und das Pech, eine Minute langsamer gewesen zu sein. :)

Answer (score 2):

Ein weiterer Kommafehler: Es ist wichtig(,) zu wissen, dass das Komma notiert werden muss und dass es eine Regel dafür gibt.
Es handelt sich um einen verschränkten Infinitiv, sprich, es hängt ein Nebensatz davon ab. Also Komma.

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Da offenbar ein Fachbegriff existiert - bitte eine Quelle verlinken, die das ebenfalls erläutert. Meist finden sich dort noch hilfreiche Details.

Comment: Sieht aber aus wie ein einfacher Infinitiv (wichtig zu wissen)