# What is the meaning of "Affenzirkus"?

Tags: translation, etymology, single-word-request, phrase, idiom

I heard someone shout:

> "Diesen Affenzirkus hier mache ich nicht länger mit!"

It seemed the person was very annoyed. What would be the meaning of *"Affenzirkus"* here? Is there a corresponding English expression? Where did this expression originate?

Comment: How does it happen that question remain without answers for 1 to [7 hours](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2316/komma-vor-dass-wenn-es-zusammen-mit-einem-verbindungswort-steht), and then there are 2 answers within minutes? `:-)`

Comment: @Hendrik Well, on this one, it could have been two people posting during their lunch break. The other one could have been breakfast :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It means that the person complains about a farce he or she is involved and wants to stop taking part in it. Sometimes *Affentheater* is used instead of *Affenzirkus*.

Dict.cc proposes this translation:

> I didn't want to play along with the charade any more.

The expression has its origin in the 19th century traveling shows:

> *Affenzirkus/Affentheater* nennt der Volksmund ein übertriebenes Gebaren, den blanken Unsinn, viel unnütze Aufregung um nichts. Ursprünglich war das »Affentheater« eine Tierschau auf Jahrmärkten: Im Europa der zweiten Hälfte des 19. Jahrhunderts ließen reisende Schausteller gern verkleidete Affen allerlei akrobatische Kunststückchen und Imitationen menschlicher Handlungen vorführen.
>
> Auch Menschen verhalten sich zuweilen wie Affen im Gehege, Vorgesetzte geben nur allzugern das Alphamännchen, die Büro-Hackordnung weist oft verblüffende Parallelen zwischen menschlichem und tierischem Verhalten auf.

([source](http://etymologie.tantalosz.de/))

Comment: +1 Your answer is better because it adds a bit of background I couldn't provide.

Comment: As a less colorful variant you can also use "Theater" or "Zirkus" alone.

Answer (score 7):

A very similar word that could be used in almost the same context is "Affentheater". I'd think english expressions that are similar to both of them are

- monkey business
- charade

So in your example, it could be something like

> I'm not putting up with this monkey business any longer!
>
> I'm not taking part in this charade any longer!

I can't answer regarding it's origins though ...