# „Was ich auch noch gut finde(,) ist, dass …“

Tags: sentence-structure, subordinate-clause, comma

Ich bin mir gerade eben nicht ganz sicher, ob das Komma in Klammern gesetzt werden sollte oder nicht. Beim Sprechen mache ich dort üblicherweise eine kleine Pause, was natürlich nicht heißen muss, dass dort auch wirklich ein Nebensatz oder ähnliches eingeleitet wird.

[Diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/2316/30847) mit [dieser Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/2317/30847) wurde mir als ähnlich vorgeschlagen, doch dort ist für mich der Fall eindeutig. Der Satz

> Ein Problem, auf das man immer wieder stoßen kann, ist, dass man nicht weiter weiß.

packt das Wort „ist“ zwischen zwei Kommas, weil es zum Hauptsatz „Das Problem ist“ gehört. In meinem Beispiel aber würde das Wort „ist“ eher seltsam in der Gegend zwischen zwei Kommas herumstehen. Von daher würde ich sagen, dass man das Komma nicht setzen sollte. Aber ich bin mir, wie gesagt, nicht ganz sicher.

Answer (score 7):

Es wird eigentlich kein Nebensatz "eingeleitet", sondern einer beendet. Der Beispielsatz

> Was ich auch noch gut finde(,) ist, dass …

enthält zwei Nebensätze: einen mit *was* eingeleiteten Prädikativsatz und einen mit  *dass* eingeleiteten Subjektsatz.

Nach dem [amtlichen Regelwerk](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2016_redigiert_2018.pdf) sind Nebensätze grundsätzlich mit Komma abzugrenzen:

> § 74. Nebensätze grenzt man mit Komma ab; sind sie eingeschoben, so
>   schließt man sie mit paarigem Komma ein.

Dort gibt es auch eine Reihe von Beispielen mit Nebensatz am Satzanfang:

> Was ich anfangen soll, weiß ich nicht. Als wir nach Hause kamen, war
>   es schon spät. Dass es dir wieder besser geht, freut mich sehr [...]

Die Ausnahme des § 76 passt mangels Formelhaftigkeit nicht auf den Beispielsatz. Insofern sollten Sie wohl am Besten ein Komma setzen.

(Ich finde dieses Ergebnis, ehrlich gesagt, auch gefühlsmäßig überhaupt nicht störend. Dann steht eben ein einzelnes Wort zwischen zwei Kommata. *So what?* Am Satzanfang stehen auch ständig einzelne Wörter isoliert zwischen Punkt und Komma. Und, wie Sie ja schon schreiben, werden die Nebensätze hier auch intonatorisch abgegrenzt, weswegen die Kommasetzung auch in dieser Hinsicht durchaus "natürlich" wirkt.)